# Why all the virtual machines I configure on portable Virtual Box do terminate during startup?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, portable-apps

I installed **Portable Virtual Box** on Windows 10 Enterprise x64 and created several Virtual Machines both Windows 7 and Linux, but I could not start any of them without getting an error.
I've been trying to reconfigure all of them individually after having removed the previous ones but I still got the error. I'm gonna post the screenshots step by step:

1) I selected "New" to create a new VM:
[image]

2) I selected the folder and saved the file:
[image]

3) This is the result. I went to the *Storage* section then, I selected *[Optical Drive] Empty* and then *Choose disk image*:
[image]

4) I selected the disk image:
[image]

5) I got the following error:
[image]

6)  I checked the **.log file** in the directory which was recommended (see the error message in the previous screenshot) to view more details. The log file is called *VBoxHardening* and reports the following text (I copypaste it on a Google document): 
[VBoxHardening log](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MVhNjyLEihOWUekBoLbwI01az3uRD4bEHiHPRhoMQTE/edit?usp=sharing)

The error message is the same both for Windows and for Linux VM.

Why all the virtual machines I configure on portable Virtual Box do terminate during startup?

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: I uploaded the content here (because the text is too long and I cannot copypaste it):
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MVhNjyLEihOWUekBoLbwI01az3uRD4bEHiHPRhoMQTE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add the new information. Comments shouldn't be used for that.

Comment: Thank you @GabrielaGarcia. Ok, I've done it

Comment: Could be your AV software blocking it. If you temporarily disable your AV, does it allow your VM to start?

Comment: @essjae thank you for your comment. I temporary disabled Avast and start the VM but I got the same issue again